# sysprep: fix "no system BCD store to be generalized"

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

Now that I've identified [why my sysprep is failing](https://serverfault.com/questions/592827/sysprep-windows-7-laptop-with-the-display-on), what do I do to fix this error?

> There is no system BCD store to be generalized. This image will not be bootable unless a system store is later created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHAH!

The Linux partition was marked as active. Marking the Windows partition as active fixed the problem.